# SDL function to clear only part of the screen?

Tags: c++, rendering, sdl

I am using C++ and SDL 2.  Is there any function in SDL or any available algorithm to clear only a part of the screen?

I tried using `SDL_RenderSetViewPort()` in the following way but it didn't work:

```
SDL_RenderSetViewPort(renderer,&rect); 
SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
```

I thought that the specific texture present in the given rectangle part would be cleared but it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

`SDL_SetRenderDrawColor()` with the clear color then `SDL_RenderFillRect()` with the desired region to 'clear'.

Comment: genpfault That doesn't works as I expected it to work. It only fills the given rectangle part with the specified Render Color but doesn't clears it